# ListView is not showing items that are added

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

**EDIT**

Got the error, it turns out it is an issue regarding the API version of the emulator. Works fine in higher API version

I am new to Android development and I am trying to build a simple to-do list where items will be added to ListView when a button is clicked. The problem is, the items are not shown in the listview, although they are added and deleted. Please help me identify what I am doing wrong.

**Here is my activity_main.xml file**

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.erfan.todolist.MainActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="368dp"
        android:layout_height="495dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editTextAddItem"
            android:hint="Enter Item"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_weight="4"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonAddItem"
            android:text="Add"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/editTextAddItem"
            android:layout_marginTop="23dp" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Here is my MainActivity.java file**

```
package com.example.erfan.todolist;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Adapter;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText vEditTextAddItem;
    Button vButtonAddItem;
    ListView vListViewItemList;
    ArrayList<String> items;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    public static final String FILENAME = "data.dat";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        vEditTextAddItem = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextAddItem);
        vButtonAddItem = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonAddItem);
        vListViewItemList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

        items = readData(getApplicationContext());

        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item, items);
        vListViewItemList.setAdapter(adapter);

        vButtonAddItem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                switch (v.getId()) {
                    case R.id.buttonAddItem:
                        String itemEntered = vEditTextAddItem.getText().toString();
                        adapter.add(itemEntered);
                        vEditTextAddItem.setText("");

                        writeData(items, getApplicationContext());

                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Item is added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                }
            }
        });

        vListViewItemList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                items.remove(position);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Item Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

    }

    public static void writeData(ArrayList<String> items, Context context) {
        try {
            FileOutputStream fileOutputStraStream = context.openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOutputStraStream);
            objectOutputStream.writeObject(items);
            objectOutputStream.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static ArrayList<String> readData(Context context) {

        ArrayList<String> itemList = null;
        try {
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = context.openFileInput(FILENAME);
            ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(fileInputStream);
            itemList = (ArrayList<String>) objectInputStream.readObject();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            itemList = new ArrayList<>();
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            itemList = new ArrayList<>();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return itemList;
    }
}
```

I am attaching the screenshot of the emulator as well

[image: adding items][image: deleteing items]

When the item is added, no item is showing in the ListView.

Comment: You missed  
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
 in bottom of 
case R.id.buttonAddItem: 
String itemEntered = vEditTextAddItem.getText().toString();
                        adapter.add(itemEntered);
                        vEditTextAddItem.setText("");

adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Answer (score 0):

Got the error, it turns out it is an issue regarding the API version of the emulator. Works fine in higher API version